# Initializing member functions fields

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, member-functions, function-qualifier

While reading the a C++1z paper called [Abominable functions](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) I've found the following code:

```
class rectangle {
    public:
    using int_property = int() const;  // common signature for several methods

    int_property top;
    int_property left;
    int_property bottom;
    int_property right;
    int_property width;
    int_property height;

    // Remaining details elided
};
```

I've never seen code like that before (the paper itself states that it is very strange to find code like that) so I wanted to give a try to this approach and give a value to those `int_property`:

```
class rectangle {
    int f() const { return 0; }
    public:
    using int_property = int() const;  // common signature for several methods

    int_property top = f; // <--- error!
    int_property left;
    int_property bottom;
    int_property right;
    int_property width;
    int_property height;

    // Remaining details elided
};
```

In my modification above, the compiler complaints about the `f` saying that `(only '= 0' is allowed) before ';' token`; my other attempts were:

```
class rectangle {
    int f() const { return 0; }
    public:
    using int_property = int() const;  // common signature for several methods

        // invalid initializer for member function 'int rectangle::top() const'
        int_property top{f};
        int_property left{&f};

        // invalid pure specifier (only '= 0' is allowed) before ';' token
        int_property bottom = f;
        int_property right = &f;

        int_property width;
        int_property height;

        // class 'rectangle' does not have any field named 'width'
        // class 'rectangle' does not have any field named 'height'
        rectangle() : width{f}, height{&rectangle::f} {}
};
```

So the question is:

- What should I do to make all the `int_property` "*fields*" point to a function?
- How to give value to all the all the `int_property` "*fields*"?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use a function signature for a variable.

Comment: This is not specific to member functions - in C++11, `int f(); using p = int(); p x = f;` g++ gives "error: function 'int x()' is initialized like a variable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int() const` is a function type with a *cv-qualifier*. The declaration `int_property top;` declares a function, not a variable. This declaration has just the same effect as `int top() const;`.

As with other member functions, you define them by providing a function definition.

```
int rectangle::top() const {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, you pointed directly on what my confussion was: I was thinking that the `int_property foo` were declaring a `foo` function pointer with the `int() const` signature which is not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That paper are introduced as Proposal #P0172R0 in 2015-11-10 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/ . I believe you are using compiler that is not supporting this functionality currently, but you can check later :). Also it might be interesting for you to read current standard http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf, or at least check what functionality currently supported by your compiler.